# Why is there space at the right of my website? (Wordpress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes

I have a wordpress site.
I don't know how this happened, but now it obviously has got a lot of spae to the right!

Can some of you see through the souce and see if you find anything suspicious?
It would be really appreciated! Thanks :)

Site: gone! :)

Comment: Seems fine. What browser are you having problems with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of your [**translation bar image**](http://www.matogvinnett.no/wp-content/plugins/global-translator/gltr_image_map.png) in line 1031.

```
<img style='border:0px;' src='http://www.matogvinnett.no/wp-content/plugins/
                              global-translator/gltr_image_map.png'
                              usemap='#gltr_flags_map'/>
```

I'ts 960 Pixels wide and forces the body to stretch to the right.

Best clip it, or give one of the surrounding containers `overflow: hidden`.

The [**Web Developer Toolbar for Firefox**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) is a great extension that helps find out such things using its "highlighter" function. I use it alongside [**Firebug**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) to debug HTML.

Comment: Thank you!
I can fix it, now that I know where the problem is :)

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the code that you have put for the flags, when i removed this code using **[firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843)**:

```
<img usemap="#gltr_flags_map" src="http://www.matogvinnett.no/wp-content/plugins/global-translator/gltr_image_map.png" style="border: 0px none;">
```

There was no more space :)